# Two equivalent (?) definitions of smooth charts

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a topological manifold and let $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ be two charts. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2532165/362026) points to condition $(1)$ below implying condition $(2)$:

1. $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}:\psi(U\cap V)\to\phi(U\cap V)$ is a diffeomorphism.
2. Given a function $f:U\cap V\to\mathbb{R}$, we have that $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is smooth if and only if so is $f\circ\psi^{-1}$.

That much I've been able to prove, but **does condition $(2)$ also imply condition $(1)$?**

If so, how would one prove it. If not, what is a counterexample.

Comment: Consider $f = \phi \vert (U\cap V)$ in condition (2).

Comment: @anomaly You can't, since in 2. $f$ has to be real valued. However, you can take $f$ any of the projection of $\phi|_{U\cap V}$ on a coordinate

Comment: @Didier: Yeah, I thought that was a typo for $\mathbb{R}^n$. But composing with the projection maps still works.

Comment: @anomaly I don't think it's a typo. The question boils down to "is the smooth structure determined by the set of smooth functions on $M$?" this way

Comment: @Didier: I don't think it is either, but I had read it that way earlier. (I also like that formulation of the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

$\phi\circ\psi^{-1}:\psi(U\cap V)\to\phi(U\cap V)$ being a diffeomorphism is equivalent to  $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$ and  $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ being smooth.

Now assume that 2. is satisfied. Let $\phi_i : U \cap V \to \mathbb R$ be the coordinate functions of $\phi \mid_{U \cap V} : U \cap V \to \phi(U \cap V) \subset \mathbb R^n$. The maps $\phi_i \circ \phi^{-1}$ are the coordinate functions of $\phi \circ \phi^{-1} = id$,  hence they are restrictions of the canonical projections $\pi_i :\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and therefore they are smooth. By 2. the maps $\phi_i \circ \psi^{-1}$ are smooth. Thus all coordinate functions of $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$ are smooth. We conclude that $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$ is smooth.

Smoothness of $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$  is proved similarly.